# How to check if at least one side of a clicked div (left or right) is free of other div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, offset, typeof

I have some div's that are 100x100px:

[image]

HTML code of the 3 blocks:

```
<div id="plane">
   <div class="tile tile3" block-id="1" style-id="3" style="left:50px; top:50px"></div>
   <div class="tile tile1" block-id="2" style-id="1" style="left:150px; top:50px"></div>
   <div class="tile tile3" block-id="3" style-id="3" style="left:250px; top:50px"></div>
</div>
```

When I click a div, I add a class called `ss` which makes the clicked div/block yellow. I have this working with the following code:

```
 el.innerHTML = html.join('');
       $(el).find('.tile').click(function () {
       var clickedBlock = $(this); 
       clickedBlock.addClass('ss'); 
 });
```

The problem is that I want to add the `ss` class ONLY to the blocks (div's) that I click and have at least one side (left or right) free. So that no other block is attached. In the case of the screenshot, the green blocks have one side clear, so these should be able to get te `ss` class when clicked. The red one has no free side, so no class should be added when I click it.

I've searched the internet for a solution and read some stuff about `offset` and `typeof` and figured I could use this. In short: click a block, get it's `style left` and `top` and check if there is any div around with the same `style left -100` (for the left side) and `+100` for the right side where `top = 0`. If there is, return true. If one side is true or both sides returns false (in that case no blocks are on the left and right), the block is "free" and the `ss` class needs to be added on the clicked block.

I have tried this code (with no success):

```
el.innerHTML = html.join('');
    $(el).find('.tile').click(function () {
        var clickedBlock = $(this); 
        var offset = $(this).offset(); //get the top and left px

        if (typeof clickedBlock[offset.left-100][offset.top=clickedBlock.attr('top')] == 'true') { //check the left side
            if (typeof clickedBlock[offset.left+100][offset.top=clickedBlock.attr('top')] == 'false') { //check the right side
                clickedBlock.addClass('ss'); 
            }
        } else { //if left side is already false, it really doesn't matter if the right side is clear or not since 1 side needs to be clear
                clickedBlock.addClass('ss'); 
        }
});
```

My question: how to make this work? Is this the best approach to do this, or are there better ways? And if so, which ones?

Also the following option is also possible:

[image]

The HTML code for this one is:

```
<div id="plane">
  <div class="tile tile3" block-id="1" style-id="3" style="left:50px; top:50px"></div>
  <div class="tile tile1" block-id="2" style-id="1" style="left:150px; top:100px"></div>
  <div class="tile tile2" block-id="3" style-id="2" style="left:50px; top:150px"></div>
  <div class="tile tile3" block-id="4" style-id="3" style="left:250px; top:150px"></div>
</div>
```

Here the green and blue blocks are "free". So in this case we need to adapt the code to also check the divs with `left-100` and `top-50`, `left-100` and `top+50`, `left+100` and `top-50`, `left+100` and `top+50`. So 6 checks in total (3 for the left and 3 for the right)

So in conclusion: if (on click) one side is free (or both) add the `ss` class. I hope my question is clear and someone can help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offence, but I think your approach is lightyears from working. You are treating a jQuery object representing a single element as a multi-dimensional array somehow magically indexed by various offsets, and then applying typeof in hope of producing a boolean? It's very late here so apologies if I'm reading it all wrong though...

EDIT: I created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/AcmLR/1/, where I have fixed a few mistakes and which seems to be working well. Code below is also updated.

Maybe try something like this:

```
var tiles = $('.tile');
tiles.click(function(){
  var me = $(this); //To save a few lookups
  /*Read out the top and left attributes, remove 'px' to 
  get the numeric part and force them to be numbers using the + (not really needed)*/
  var myLeft = +me.css('left').replace('px', '');
  var myTop = +me.css('top').replace('px', '');
  var leftFree = true, rightFree = true; //Assume both sides are free to begin with
  tiles.not(me).each(function(){
    if(!leftFree && !rightFree){
      return; //No need processing any more boxes
    }
    var me = $(this); //To save a few lookups
    var left = +me.css('left').replace('px', '');
    var top = +me.css('top').replace('px', '');
    if(top < myTop-100 || top > myTop+100){
      return; //This box is completely above or below the clicked box
    }
    if(left == myLeft-100){
      leftFree = false;
      return;
    }
    if(left == myLeft+100){
      rightFree = false;
      return;
    }
  });
  if(leftFree || rightFree){
    me.addClass('ss'); //In this scope me still refers to the clicked box
  }
});
```

Depending on your exact requirements, whether the boxes may move or not etc, there may solutions that are more efficient or more compact.

Comment: thanks you for the reply Peter Herdenborg. I understand what you try to do with the code and if I read it correctly it should do what I need it to do. Unfortunately I didn't got it working. ps my blocks do not move

Comment: Late reply, but this looks good (didn't received a notice that you've edited your answer). Going to play around with. Thanks a million!

Comment: Maurice, sorry, I must have forgotten to mention that I updated my answer. Thanks for accepting!

Comment: No problem. I have played around with it and it works great. I want to extend the code a bit so that a covered `div` can't be clicked as well. To achieve this, Ive added in the div the attribute (apologies if this isn't the correct term): `floor="1"` and the next layer has `floor="2"`. I've started trying to check first if a div is covered or not. If it is, we don't have to check the sides. If not covered we need to check the sides. Made a clean fiddle (without my attempts) where the green divs are on floor 2: http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/xTKG7/4/ any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your example it seems like you could just say:

```
$('.tile').on({
    click : function () {
        if($(this).css('left') != '150px') {
            $(this).addClass('ss');
        }
    }
});
```

Since only divs in the middle would ever have that specific declaration you would always know that it's whatever was clicked was an outer div.

This works if your code is routinely this specific. If it's more dynamic and flowing (say a group of divs floated left) you could do something similar to what you posted above:

```
$('.tile').on({
    click : function () {
        var prevEleOffSet = $(this).prev('.tile').offset().left,
            nextEleOffSet = $(this).next('.tile').offset().left,
            thisEleOffSet = $(this).offset().left;

        if(prevEleOffSet > thisEleOffSet || nextEleOffSet < thisEleOffSet) {
            $(this).addClass('ss');
        }
    }
});
```

First, we check if the prev('.tile') of our clicked $('.tile') is farther left on the screen. If it is, we can assume it is on the row above. If it turns out the prev('.tile') is on the same row we check the next('.tile'). If it's not as far left as our clicked $('.tile') than we can assume it is on the next row down, and not right next to our clicked div.

If either of those statements are true we slap your class on, turn it yellow, and go about our business.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply TristanZimmerman. This seems to work (got some issues to figure out), but it doesn't seem to work on my second part, the blocks blocking one part for half the side.

Answer (score 0):

I will try something, but this may not work for all cases

1st - I would loop through all the div inside that box and collect "left" css value (Jquery offset or css) and store them into an array. But I don't collect them all, I just take an unique value. So 5 div with left of (50,50,150,200,200). I will collect only (50,150,200). (this can easily be done with a while loop).

2nd - check if the array length > 2 or not. if <=2 than every boxes can turn yellow.

3rd - if >2, than only the first and last value are values of boxes that can turn yellow

Again, this will ideally work when you have a single row, if you have more than 1 row, you have to check their alignment with each other...

That was my best shot @_o